# Composer post-autoload-dump for dev

Tags: composer-php

I am use composer `post-autoload-dump` functionality but i want two version of it, one for when we require dev tools and one for when we don't.

More specifically in out `post-autoload-dump` list we have two commands that we don't want to run when using `composer install --no-dev` in the below snippet it's the `@php artisan ide-helper:generate` and the `@php artisan ide-helper:meta` commands as this breaks the execution if those dev packages aren't present

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
      "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
      "@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
    ],
}
```

So i'm looking for something along the lines of :

```
"post-autoload-dump": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
    "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
],
"post-autoload-dump-dev": [
    "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
    "@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Laravel I just created my own command and did my logic in there. Basically `if(class_exists('\The\Class'))` then run the command, else don't.

```
"post-autoload-dump": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
    "@php artisan setup:post-autoload-dump"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people run into problems with this while deploying to their live server, running composer with the --no-dev flag. In this case artisan will not be able to find the packages and will fail to run the script.

You can write a dev-helper command that only runs on your local environment (where you likely have the dev packages installed) like this:

App/Console/Commands/DevHelpers.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    use Illuminate\Console\Command;

    class DevHelpers extends Command
    {
        protected $signature = 'dev-helpers:run';
        protected $description = 'run development scripts on env=local only';
        
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function handle()
        {
            if (config('app.env') === 'local') {
                $this->info('generating ide helper files...');
                $this->call('ide-helper:generate');
                $this->call('ide-helper:meta');
                $this->info('... generating ide helper files done');
            }
        }
    }
```

App/Console/Kernel.php:

```
// at the top
use App\Console\Commands\DevHelpers;

// in the commands array
protected $commands = [
    DevHelpers::class, // add this command
    ...
]
```

composer.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
        "@php artisan dev-helpers:run"
    ],
```